# Finding if there relationship between numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

I have a challenge. This may be little tricky or even not possible but wanted to check if anyone has any thoughts on this?

PS : This question is in general and not related to only to R. May be I can say its general mathematics

I have a data

```
df
ColA    ColB    ColC
 6       9       27
 1       4       32
 4       8       40
```

If you observe closely, there is some relationship between these columns.

Example, (ColC/ColB)+ColA will give you number 9.

```
df
ColA    ColB    ColC   ColD
 6       9       27     9
 1       4       32     9
 4       8       40     9
```

However this data is manipulated and I made sure there is some relation. But in general, lets us take any numbers, is there a way to find if there is any relationship between these numbers. Need not be (ColC/ColB)+ColA . It could be anything.

Say we have 5 columns of numeric data. I need to find mathematical operation between these so that common number exists.

This is more into mathematics(algebra). Can anyone let me know is this even possible ?

Comment: Thanks. Can you share more inputs so that I can google it. Or if there is any material that would be helpful

Comment: There are a number of programs like Eureqa and  Mathematica that can do similar things with a single sequence, but I am not familiar enough with the field to know what software if any would deal with a bunch of related sequences as in your case. In many applications, you'd know what sort of relationship to expect and could narrow your search.

Comment: There are infinitely many possible relations giving the same result for given data. There is also universal formula colA·0+colB·0+…=0.

Answer (score 1):

For finitely many given points in $\Bbb Q^3$ we can find a polynomial $f(x,y,z)\in \Bbb Q[x,y,z]$, which vanishes at these points. For example, for your points
$$
u=(6,9,29), v=(1,4,32), w=(4,8,40)
$$
the polynomial you have found is
$$
f(x,y,z)=xy-9y+z.
$$
Indeed $f(u)=f(v)=f(w)=0$, and this corresponds to your "rule" $\frac{z}{y}+x=9$.

On the other hand, there are many more choices. For example, we can also find
$$
f(x,y,z)=4x^2 - 35xy + 4xz + 264x - 2yz
$$
Then also $f(6,9,27)=f(1,4,32)=f(4,8,40)=0$. This looks more complicated, but it shows that we have many choices, and that this will work.

For reference see [Polynomial interpolation in several variables](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjvyY2OiMb4AhWW76QKHSU4D6QQFnoECAIQAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpcmap.unizar.es%2F%7Egasca%2Finvestig%2FGSSurvey.pdf&usg=AOvVaw15-LwlwhOxbA_HPRd5CPXp).

Comment: Really thanks for the time

Answer (score 0):

> But in general, lets us take any numbers, is there a way to find if there is any relationship between these numbers. Need not be (ColC/ColB)+ColA . It could be anything.

The 'it could be anything' makes this problem trivial. As Ivan points out in the comments, you can always do:

$$ColA*0+ColB*0+ColC*0 ...$$

or (if you don;t want to use constants in your formula):

$$(ColA-ColA)+(ColB-ColB)+(ColC-ColC) ...$$

both of which will always return $0$

So, to make this an interesting problem, you'll need to put some constraints on the formula, e.g.

- Are constants allowed?
- Can you have multiple instances of $ColA$ (and same for others)?
- And most importantly: What operators are allowed?  Addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, exponentiation, square root, etc. etc. ?

Note that if constants are not allowed, if you can use only one (or some predefined limited number of) instances of $ColA$, and restrict yourself to a fixed and defined number of operators, then there are only finitely many formulas that you can make, and so a computer would be able to quickly go through all those and see if something works.